# Max and min of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For real numbers a,b, I define $\land$ and $\lor$ as:

$$a \land b = \min \{a, b\} $$
$$a \lor b = \max \{a,b\} $$

Now I want to proof the the distributive properties:

$$a \land (b \lor c) = (a \land b)\lor(a \land c)$$
$$a \lor (b \land c) = (a \lor b)\land(a \lor c)$$

I have done it already like this:

First case: $a<b<c$, then ...

Second case: $a<c<b$, then ...

But this takes me ages, is there a short and neat way to prove this? Any hints or ideas would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need both cases because usages of $b$ and $c$ are symmetric.